# Apostrophes in php code

Tags: php, url

Can I have the following code:

```
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
echo '<div class="wwd">
<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '"><img src="/images/' . $category->name . $category->term_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $categories->category_name . '" /></a>
<div class="wwd-title"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></div><br/>
</div>';
}
```

I am trying to add this code before /images/

```
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>
```

At present the code generates the img src="/images/..." but I want the sites url to go before the /images, when I have tried it I cant seem to get it to either work or display the correct path. The problem seems to with the apostrophe types used but I cant seem to figure out what should go where.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Show us `blobinfo` function.

Comment: @hd. `bloginfo` is a [wordpress function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the wordpress `bloginfo` function outputs the data to the browser. Instead use [get_template_directory_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) to save the result to a variable:

```
$templateurl = get_template_directory_uri();
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<div class="wwd">
    <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '"><img src="' . $templateurl . '/images/' . $category->name . $category->term_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $categories->category_name . '" /></a>
    <div class="wwd-title"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></div><br/>
    </div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`bloginfo` will try to echo out the value of the parameter specified so you should try another method of just getting the information you want it. Say for example `bloginfo` returned your template directory you could do this:

```
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<div class="wwd">
    <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '"><img src="' . bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/' . $category->name . $category->term_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $categories->category_name . '" /></a>
    <div class="wwd-title"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></div><br/>
    </div>';
}
```

The `get_template_directory` function might be more appropriate: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory